Ubuntu desktop always suddenly crashes and returns to the login screen
I use x11vnc to login to the remote Ubuntu server. Sometimes (not always) when I close VSCode or open a new VSCode window, the desktop suddenly has no response and Ubuntu returns to the login screen after a while. Can someone help me to find the reason for this or give an instruction to debug it?
The attached links are the log files,_usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash, Xorg.0.log, Xorg.0.log.old

sorry, I forgot to change the access right. Is the link available for download now?

Yes, it's available.
